# vector of boost sockets

Tags: c++, sockets, c++11, boost

I want to design a mechanism with one server and several clients using boost C++ library such that server will have multiple boost sockets connected to each client with a distinct port number.  To access these sockets later I want to have an array like structure of these sockets or may be a vector.  I have tried to design it like below, but it is giving numerous errors.

```
std::vector<tcp::socket> sockets_;  
std::vector<tcp::acceptor> acceptors_;

boost::asio::io_service io_service;
tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port_no));
tcp::socket socket(io_service);
acceptor.accept(socket);
port_no++;
sockets_.push_back(socket);
acceptors_.push_back(acceptor);
```

I want to access each sockets like `acceptor[]` and `socket[]`.  Is it possible to do it in C++ or there is any other way, because if the number of client varies I cannot hard code it.  Please help if anyone has any prior knowledge or experience to deal with such problems.
Thank you,

Comment: The design idea is fine. What are the "numerous errors" ? And why different port numbers ?

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. And when editing your question to include that, also include the actual errors you get (in full, complete and unedited). Also please point out where in the shown source (with e.g. comments) you get the errors.

Comment: also it may be important whether you work in C++98 or C++11, because a vector needs elements with copy constructor in C++98, but I think move constructors of C++11 weaken that requirement.

Comment: @Drax I have used different port numbers because I feel that different clients cannot connect to a single server on the same port, so each client will have a dedicated socket along with its port number and acceptor.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I will get the server version and the client versions and edit the question soon. Thank you.

Comment: @marek.jancuska I am using c++11

Comment: different ports - this is not necessary, just think of all users of stackoverflow, they all connect to stackoverflow.com:80.

Comment: @user7689454 I'm not saying that changing your server port at each connection wouldn't be a fun game for the client or that it doesn't increase the protection against hackers, but honestly, don't :)
Your client is not supposed to know how many other clients before him did connect to your server, which is a necessary info to know what's the next port to connect to is going to be, am not even talking about what if you come to a port that is already used ?

Comment: @Drax I got your point. I wasn't aware of this fact. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need multiple acceptors and you don't need multiple ports (usually). Just keep accepting clients on the same port. `Boost.Asio` has great tutorials, e.g. check [this one](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.html#boost_asio.tutorial.tutdaytime2)

This should greatly simplify your server and even more your clients.

Comment: suppose in the first round I am sending a sentence to each client and using the same acceptor and socket I can do it efficiently. But after some time if the server wants to send a sentence to all the clients, then the connect() and accept operations have to be called again or not??

Comment: you have one acceptor that is waiting on a predefined port for incoming connections. Each client normally connects once. You store sockets accepted by your acceptor in a vector. When you need to broadcast something to all clients, you send a network packet to all these sockets, as many times as you wish, until either server or client closes connection explicitly.

Comment: Thank you, I will try implementing it for my problem.